# Bind dataprovider DataGrid to an Array

Tags: apache-flex, binding

How do you bind the dataprovider of a DataGrid in Flex to an Array?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
<mx:DataGrid 
    id="valuesDataGrid" 
    editable="true" 
    width="100%" 
    height="100%" 
    dataProvider="{_metaDataKey.values}">
...

[Bindable]
public class EnumMetaDataKey{

    private var _values:Array = [];

    public function get values():Array { return _values; }
    public function set values(value:Array):void { _values = value; }
    ...
```

Comment: Where are you getting _metaDataKey from?  What does that variable look like? What errors are you getting with your current implementation?  Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `ArrayCollection` instead. `Array`s do not lend well to binding. IIRC, this is documented in the Flex 3 help on [Binding to functions Objects and Arrays](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/databinding_4.html):

> **Note:** When defining a data binding expression that uses an array as the source of a data binding expression, the array should be of type `ArrayCollection` because the `ArrayCollection` class dispatches an event when the array or the array elements change to trigger data binding. For example, a call to `ArrayCollection.addItem()`, `ArrayCollection.addItemAt()`, `ArrayCollection.removeItem()`, and `ArrayCollection.removeItemAt()` all trigger data binding.